# ffmpeg convert mp4 to mov with dnxhd codec

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, mp4, codec, davinci-resolve

I'd like to convert an mp4 file to DNxHD for use with DaVinci Resolve.

Here is my attempt of doing the conversion using ffmpeg:

```
C:\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe  -i "H:\Downloads\test.mp4" -vcodec dnxhd   "H:\Downloads\test.mov"
```

It fails and outputs:

```
  starting ffe job on 2017-02-08 @ 14:56:24.487
  command-line: C:\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe  -i "H:\Downloads\test.mp4" -vcodec dnxhd   "H:\Downloads\test.mov"

  ffmpeg version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
    configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
    libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
    libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
    libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
    libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
    libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
    libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
    libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
    libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
  Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'H:\Downloads\test.mp4':
    Metadata:
      major_brand     : isom
      minor_version   : 512
      compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
      title           : 1296227453771893
      encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Duration: 00:00:35.50, start: -0.020000, bitrate: 2227 kb/s
      Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x1280, 2196 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
      Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 47 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
  File 'H:\Downloads\test.mov' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] video parameters incompatible with DNxHD. Valid DNxHD profiles:
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 175Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 24000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 185Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 365Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 50/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 440Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 60000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 115Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 24000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 120Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 145Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 30000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 240Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 50/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 290Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 60000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 175Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 24000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 185Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 220Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 30000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 365Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 50/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 440Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 60000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 185Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 220Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 30000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 120Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 145Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 30000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 185Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080i; bitrate: 220Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 30000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 120Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 145Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 30000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 90Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 24000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 90Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 180Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 50/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 220Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 60000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 90Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 24000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 90Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 110Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 30000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 180Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 50/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 220Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 60000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 60Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 24000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 60Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 75Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 30000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 120Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 50/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1280x720p; bitrate: 145Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 60000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 36Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 24000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 36Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 45Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 30000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 75Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 50/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 90Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 60000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 350Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 24000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 390Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 25/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 440Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 30000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 730Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 50/1
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 880Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p10; framerate: 60000/1001
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 960x720p; bitrate: 42Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 960x720p; bitrate: 60Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 960x720p; bitrate: 75Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 960x720p; bitrate: 115Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1440x1080p; bitrate: 63Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1440x1080p; bitrate: 84Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1440x1080p; bitrate: 100Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1440x1080p; bitrate: 110Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 80Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 90Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 100Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  [dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1440x1080i; bitrate: 110Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 0/0
  Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> dnxhd (native))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
  Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

  Completed in 2.15886844137404 seconds (2.16 seconds)
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Like the error says: `video parameters incompatible with DNxHD`. Your input is 1280x1280@24fps, but only the listed resolutions are acceptable. You'll have to scale down and add (black) padding to make it work. If that's ok, I'll post a command.

Answer (score 3):

Your output has to match one of the requested profiles.

For the 5th profile listed,

```
[dnxhd @ 0000000002be23a0] Frame size: 1920x1080p; bitrate: 115Mbps; pixel format: yuv422p; framerate: 24000/1001
```

you would use

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -vf format=yuv422p,scale=-1:1080,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:0 -r 24000/1001 -c:v dnxhd -b:v 115M out.mov
```

Comment: If you receive a `syntax error near unexpected token (` error, enclose the whole `format` value in double quotes, like this: `ffmpeg -i test.mov -vf format="yuv422p,scale=-1:1080,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:0" -r 24000/1001 -c:v dnxhd -b:v 115M out.mov`